# how to read parameter with window.open in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, popupwindow

I need to call an ASPX page from MVC view through below JavaScript code, also need to pass some parameter as query string,

```
function OpenTest() {
    var width = (screen.availWidth - 700).toString();
    var height = (screen.availHeight - 100).toString();
    var param1 = "Test";
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Test/Test.aspx?")';
    window.open(baseUrl + "param1=" + param1);
}
```

In ASPX page,

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["param1"]))
        {
            string s1 = Request.QueryString["param1"];
        }
```

I am able to call ASPX page and read parameter value by above code, but when I add other property of "window.open", I am not able to read query string, question is where should I place below property in above code so that I can also read query string value in ASPX page,

```
"mywindow", "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",toolbar=no,location=no,directories=yes,status=no," +
            "menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes" + ",screenX=0,screenY=0,left=0,top=0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `window.open()` is:

```
window.open('url/for/page/here.aspx', 'targetName', 'options');
```

The `targetName` can be "_self", "_blank", "_parent", just like any target attribute for links, or have an identifier to name the window, so you can reuse the window when openning with the same name.

When you calll `window.open()` with any option to restrict the window, like `width=100` it assumes that all the other have to be disabled, so you don't have to put the properties you want to disable.

Fixing your options would be:

```
window.open(baseUrl + "param1=" + param1,
    "mywindow",
    "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",directories=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes,screenX=0,screenY=0,left=0,top=0");
```

Another thing to note is that all options have to be separated by comas, without spaces. Some browsers ignore/missinterpret options with spaces.

Also, don't forget to escape the variables to pass with the url.